# How do I give permission to access "/server-status?" on a specific IP address?

Tags: permissions

What file do I edit in my apache2 folder that will give a specific IP address permission to access my "server-status?" page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same way you grant access to any other location:

```
<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost 10.3.4.5 
</Location>
```

Replace `10.3.4.5` with whatever IP you want to whitelist.

Comment: Which file would I add this to?

Comment: This depends completely on how your server is set up. If it's a Debian-derivative, probably in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/status.conf`.

Comment: So I added my computer's LAN IPV4 address to the list and then tried accessing it and it still doesn't work. I'm still getting a Forbidden 403 error.

Comment: You need to restart apache after the change.